# Modular arithmetic

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

How do I prove the following inequality with modular arithmetic? (No use of Fermat's last theorem is allowed.)

$$3987^{12} + 4365^{12} \neq 4472^{12}$$

Comment: Consider each term modulo $3$.

Answer (score 7):

Fermat's last theorem is the most obvious way.

A more elementary proof could use Fermat's little theorem:

$$(3987)^{12} \equiv (4365)^{12} \equiv 1 \; \bmod 13,$$ but $(4472)^{12} \equiv 0 \; \bmod 13$ because $13$ divides $4472$.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $3|3987,3|4365,3\not| 4472$ so we have $3^{12}a^{12}+3^{12}b^{12}=4472^{12}\implies 3|4472,\text{ and }3\not| 4472\implies 3987^{12}+4365^{12}\ne 4472^{12}.$

Answer (score 0):

My first intuition is to use modular arithmetic.

Note that 3986 = 4000 - 14 and so 3987 = 3 mod 4.  Now

$$(3987)^2 \space mod \space 4 = 9 \space mod \space 4 = 1$$

$$\text{and so }3987^{12} = 1 \space mod \space 4$$

Now, we also use the fact that

$$4365 \space mod \space 4 = 1$$

$$\text{and so }4365^12 = 1 \space mod \space 4$$

So, one side is 2 mod 4, but the other side is a square, since

$$4472^{12} = (4472^6)^2$$

Now, if 4472 is 2 mod 4, then

$$4472^2 = 0 \space mod \space 4$$

$$\text{and so }4472^{12} = 0 \space mod \space 4$$

Hence, this proves that the sides are not equivalent mod 4 and we are done.

Comment: Perhaps you meant $3986^{12}\equiv 0\mod 4$?

Comment: Erratum: meant to say that $$3987^{12} \equiv 1 \space mod \space 4$$ as opposed to $$3986^{12} \equiv 1 \space mod \space 4$$

Comment: Much easier is to observe $3987\equiv -1 \bmod 4$, and $4365\equiv 1 \bmod 4$, and $4472 \equiv 0 \bmod 4$, so the equation would require $(-1)^{12}+1^{12}\equiv 0^{12} \Rightarrow 2 \equiv 0 \bmod 4$, an obvious falsity.

Answer (score 0):

$3987$ and $4365$ are both divisible by 3, and $4472$ is not.

So the left hand side is divisible by 3, and the right hand side is not.

Thus the two can't be equal.